# Azure Ad B2c Custom Policy with nextauth

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

i have integrated azure ad b2c userflows in my application and it is working fine but i need some customization in the user flows. So I made some custom policies and validated policies deployed as instructed in azure ad b2c tutorial and every thing is working fine if try run those policies thourgh azure portal. I am using NextJs and NextAuth for authentication service. NextAuth provides azure Ad B2c Provider which is working fine for userflow as soon as i change userflow name with custom policy name i am getting error while signing up and signing in. Is NextAuth AzureAdB2CProvider compatible with azure ad b2c custom policies and how can i integrate that in my application?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import config from 'config/config'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import AzureADB2CProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad-b2c'

const b2cProviderName = 'azure-ad-b2c'
const nextAuthUrl = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL
const clientId = process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID
const tenantName = process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME
const tenantGuid = process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_GUID
const clientSecret = process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET
const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET
let userFlow = process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW

async function refreshAccessToken(token: any) {
  try {
    const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantGuid}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
    const response = await axios.post(
      url,
      {
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        scope: 'offline_access openid',
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: token.refresh_token
      },
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      }
    )

    return {
      ...token
      // id_token: refreshedTokens.id_token,
      // id_token_expires_at: refreshedTokens.expires_at * 1000,
      // refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refresh_token // Fall back to old refresh token
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)

    return {
      ...token,
      error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError'
    }
  }
}
export const authOptions: any = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/',
    signOut: '/auth/signout'
  },
  session: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 60
  },
  secret: jwtSecret,
  callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }: any) {
      return baseUrl
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }: any) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          `${config.SERVER}/api/user/createUser`,
          {},
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token.id_token}`
            }
          }
        )
        if (token && response?.data?.payload) {
          session.id_token = token.id_token
          session.refresh_token = token.refresh_token
          session.id_token_expires_in = token.id_token_expires_in
          session.refresh_token_expires_in = token.refresh_token_expires_in
          session.firstName = response?.data?.payload?.firstname || ''
          session.roles = response?.data?.payload?.roles || []
          session.user.id = response?.data?.payload?.azure_id || ''
        }
        return session
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)

        return undefined
      }
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }: any) {
      if (account) {
        token.id_token = account.id_token
        token.refresh_token = account.refresh_token
        token.id_token_expires_in = account.id_token_expires_in
        token.id_token_expires_at = account.expires_at * 1000
        token.refresh_token_expires_in = account.refresh_token_expires_in
        token.firstName = profile.name
      }
      // if (Date.now() < token.id_token_expires_at) {
      //   return token
      // }
      // return refreshAccessToken(token)
      return token
    }
  },
  providers: [
    AzureADB2CProvider({
      tenantId: tenantName,
      clientId: clientId || '',
      clientSecret: clientSecret || '',
      primaryUserFlow: userFlow,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: `https://${tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read https://${tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.write offline_access openid`,
          p: `${userFlow}`
        }
      },
      checks: ['pkce'],
      client: {
        token_endpoint_auth_method: 'none'
      }
    })
  ]
}

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  return NextAuth(req, res, authOptions)
}
```

here is my [nextauth].tsx file for reference

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get with custom policies?

You may have to use [AppInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to look at the logs.

Do the custom policies work if you use the "Run Now" button on the portal?

In theory, all you need to do is change the policy name, which should work.

Comment: okay i am getting server_error on signin and "status":"400","errorCode":"AADB2C90278","message":"Unable to validate the information provided." on Singup and no it is same with run now button, it produces same errors

Comment: The usual cause of this error is that you haven't set up the keys correctly or the app registrations for the two Framework applications - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy

Comment: Or use this - https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/